# Using $(this).addClass is not working in AJAX success

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am doing some ajax processing on click event that working fine but now I want to add `class`  on success function I am using `$(this).addClass("cover");` but nothing is happening . If I target class for add class mean if I use like this `$('.dz-cover').addClass("cover");`  it works fine but it add class all link tag that is with class name `'.dz-cover'` I don't want I just only want to add class only that link in which I am clicking. My code is below

```
$("#dropzonePreview").on("click", "a.dz-cover", function () {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'attachment/cover',
        data: {id: id},
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            $(this).addClass("cover");                   
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because context of element `a.dz-cover` is lost in ajax call, you can set context in ajax calls using option context:

```
$("#dropzonePreview").on("click", "a.dz-cover", function () {

var id = $(this).data('id');
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'attachment/cover',
    context:this,
    data: {id: id},
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (data) {
        $(this).addClass("cover");

    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Not working. Now something strange is happening if i click one link class does not add on that link now i click on anther link now class is adding but not that in which click now it is adding on that link in which i click before

Comment: @MuhammadUmar: you should show loader on click and then hide it in success function.

Answer (score 2):

`this` will not work in this case, because `success` is another block.

```
$("#dropzonePreview").on("click", "a.dz-cover", function () {
    var elm = $(this);
    var id = elm.data('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'attachment/cover',
        data: { id: id },
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            elm.addClass("cover");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It should work. Can you make a fiddle? @MuhammadUmar

Comment: Now something strange is happening if i click one link class does not add on that link now i click on anther link now class is adding but not that in which click now it is adding on that link in which i click before

Comment: Can you make a fiddle with your working code? @MuhammadUmar

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `$(this)` out of context. You should set it to a variable to be able to use it within your AJAX callback like so:

```
$("#dropzonePreview").on("click", "a.dz-cover", function () {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var element = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'attachment/cover',
        data: {id: id},
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            element.addClass("cover");

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It still not working